# Literal control not displaying rendered HTML

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms, literals

I am storing HTML in a database and trying to render it on a page using a literal control. The problem is that the literal is not rendering the code and is instead just displaying the markup on the web page. I have checked the HTML and it works fine when added directly to the page but does not work when set as the literals text property.

I have done this many times before, in face I have re-used the code but for some reason only the markup is showing.

Literal on page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentArea" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough"></asp:Literal>
</asp:Content>
```

VB Code:

```
   Private Sub LoadContent()

        Dim strConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString

        Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection

        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
                .ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString

        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand

        cmd.CommandText = ("select HTML from Pages where " & _
                           "PageName like @SearchText + '%'")

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", "TheShop")
        cmd.Connection = conn
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        conn.Open()
        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While sdr.Read
            sb.Append(sdr("HTML")) _
                .Append(Environment.NewLine)
        End While
        conn.Close()
        Literal1.Text = sb.ToString


    End Sub
```

This is the contents of sb.ToString before it is added to the literal:

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="color:#FF0000"&gt;revergveraer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="color:#FF0000"&gt;&lt;img alt="" src="http://pngimg.com/upload/fish_PNG1156.png" style="height:133px; width:200px" /&gt;rgergerg&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

This is the HTML that is output and shown as markup by the literal:

```
<p><span style="color:#FF0000">revergveraer</span></p> <p><span style="color:#FF0000"><img alt="" src="http://pngimg.com/upload/fish_PNG1156.png" style="height:133px; width:200px" />rgergerg</span></p>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce, I see the fish. Did you take the last snippet from the database or from the displayed web page? Can you either post the exact value from the DB or put in a breakpoint and post the value of SB.ToString? There might be characters we cannot see that are causing your issue.

Comment: @Steve I have added the contents of sb.tostring. The literal seems to transform it into correct HTML but it does not render it, it simply shows the code in the webpage. I also just tried a similar approached using a panel by added a label to it and it produced the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HTML is encoded and needs to be decoded before it can be rendered through the Literal. This is easy with `Server.HtmlDecode`.

```
Literal1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(sb.ToString)
```

However, I would suggest you do NOT use `Environment.NewLine` as you are in your code but instead use:

```
sb.append("<br/>")
```